# JQuery Datatables Close Each Open Row with fnClose()

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make a Button which closes *onClick* all opened *tr* in my Datatable.

I'm opening the rows with the following command :

```
oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'newtr');
```

Is there a simply possibility to close all opened *tr* rows in my Datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your trying to accomplish the same thing i was which is when i open a second row i want the previous row to close.

Meaning i would only be able to display one rows details at a time.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var previousTr;
    oTable = $('#bookingstable').dataTable
         ({
             "aoColumnDefs": [
                 { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 15] }
             ]
         });


    $('#bookingstable tbody td').live('click', function () {
        var selectedTr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
        if (oTable.fnIsOpen(previousTr)  && previousTr != selectedTr)) {
            oTable.fnClose(previousTr);
        }
        if (oTable.fnIsOpen(selectedTr)) {
            oTable.fnClose(selectedTr);
        }
        else {
            oTable.fnOpen(selectedTr, fnDetailsRow(selectedTr), 'details-row');
            previousTr = selectedTr;
        }
    });
});
function fnDetailsRow(selectedTr) {
    var TrData = oTable.fnGetData(selectedTr);
    var detailsRow = '<table border="0">';
    detailsRow += '<tr><td class="space" rowspan="4"><br /><h1>⇉</h1></td><td     class="LabelField">Passenger Name</td><td class="ValueField">' + TrData[3] + '</td><td class="LabelField" rowspan="2">Pickup Details</td><td class="ValueField" rowspan="2">' + TrData[14] + '</td><td class="LabelField" rowspan="2">Customer Notes</td><td class="ValueField" rowspan="2">' + TrData[9] + '</td></tr>';
    detailsRow += '<tr><td class="LabelField">Phone Number</td><td class="ValueField">' + TrData[2] + '</td></tr>';
    detailsRow += '<tr><td class="LabelField">Car Type</td><td class="ValueField">' + TrData[6] + '</td><td class="LabelField" rowspan="2">Dropoff Details</td><td class="ValueField"  rowspan="2">' + TrData[15] + '</td><td class="LabelField" rowspan="2">Office Notes</td><td class="ValueField" rowspan="2">' + TrData[12] + '</td></tr>';
    detailsRow += '<tr><td class="LabelField">Pax and Bags</td><td class="ValueField">' + TrData[7] + ' Paxs & ' + TrData[8] + ' Bags' + '</td></tr>';
    return detailsRow;
}
```

Notice I am declaring a `var previousTr` on document ready and checking it before opening any 2nd row. remembering of course to set it again once you've opened a new row.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for..  thank you so much for your effort

Answer (score 1):

After having initialized your datatable, you can bind click event on all tr and close selected row using :

```
oTable.$('tr').click(function(){
   if ( oTable.fnIsOpen(this) ) {
      oTable.fnClose( this );
   }
});
```

Please see [here](http://www.datatables.net/api) for further documentation about datatable API.

Comment: As teachers says, there is no stupid questions, only ones that nobody dare to ask. Sure it will help more than only you.