# JQuery DataTable: Close an Open row once I open/click on another row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm working on a Jquery DataTables legacy project. I'm trying to add a feature. If I click a row to show it's detail, I can automatically close that same row by opening up another one. 
Right now the logic is I can open multiple rows at once but have to click the same row to close it.

```
   ...
    eventsTableOpenDetails[0] = openBtn; //html image
        eventsTableOpenDetails[1] = nTr;     // current inner tr
    .....

        if(eventsTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)){
            openBtn.src = "images/details_open.png";
            eventsTable.fnClose(nTr);
        }
        else {
            var aData = eventsTable.fnGetData(nTr);
            var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; word-wrap:break-word;table-layout: fixed;">';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Cnt:</td><td>' + aData[1] + '</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Time:</td><td>' + aData[2] + '</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Type:</td><td>' + aData[3] + '</td></tr>';
            //sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Field 5:</td><td>' + aData[5] + '</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Details:</td><td><pre>' + aData[6] + '</pre></td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%"></td><td></td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%"></td><td><button id="btnClientInject" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onclick="injectData( ' + position + ' );" >Inject</button></td></tr>';
            sOut += '</table>';


            openBtn.src = "images/details_close.png";
            eventsTable.fnOpen(nTr, sOut, 'details');

        }
```

I look at a previous question that addressed the same issue but didn't know how the browser knew the variable "pTr" was a previously clicked event in the DOM. 
[JQuery Datatables Close Each Open Row with fnClose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507000/jquery-datatables-close-each-open-row-with-fnclose)

Thank you.

edit: the pTr was pointing to the current nTr. I didn't realized that before.. this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what I did wrong here is the correct code:

```
//store state of open rows
//global variables
var currentExpanded;
var currentExpandedImg;

 if(eventsTable.fnIsOpen(currentExpanded) && currentExpanded!=nTr){

        currentExpandedImg.src = "images/details_open.png";
        eventsTable.fnClose(currentExpanded);

    }
    if(eventsTable.fnIsOpen(nTr)){

        openBtn.src = "images/details_open.png";
        eventsTable.fnClose(nTr);
    }
    else {
        var aData = eventsTable.fnGetData(nTr);
        var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="attribute=isClose; padding-left:50px; border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; word-wrap:break-word;table-layout: fixed;">';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Cnt:</td><td>' + aData[1] + '</td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Time:</td><td>' + aData[2] + '</td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Type:</td><td>' + aData[3] + '</td></tr>';
        //sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Field 5:</td><td>' + aData[5] + '</td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%">Details:</td><td><pre>' + aData[6] + '</pre></td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%"></td><td></td></tr>';
        sOut += '<tr><td style="width:10%"></td><td><button id="btnClientInject" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onclick="injectData( ' + position + ' );" >Inject</button></td></tr>';
        sOut += '</table>';


        openBtn.src = "images/details_close.png";
        currentExpandedImg = openBtn;
        eventsTable.fnOpen(nTr, sOut, 'details');
        currentExpanded = nTr;
    }
```